# Wordpress does not recognize PHP update on Ubuntu 18.04 droplet with PHP 7.4.3 from repos

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress does not recognize PHP update on Ubuntu 18.04 droplet with PHP 7.4.3 from repos.

It states I have PHP version 7.

How to make WP accept the update?

I have this in my .htaccess

```
# END WordPress
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value memory_limit 400M
php_value max_execution_time 180
php_value max_input_time 180


# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value auto_prepend_file '/var/www/html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

WP_DEBUG true gives no errors

```
root@benja2:~# a2enmod php7.4
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.4:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Considering conflict php5 for php7.4:
Enabling module php7.4.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
systemctl restart apache2
root@benja2:~# systemctl restart apache2
root@benja2:~#
```

I have this in my wordfence-waf.php

```
<?php
// Before removing this file, please verify the PHP ini setting        `auto_prepend_file` does not point to this.

if (file_exists('/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence    /waf/bootstrap.php')) {
    define("WFWAF_LOG_PATH", '/var/www/html/wp-content/wflogs/');
    include_once '/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence    /waf/bootstrap.php';
}
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the php5 module.
Then type

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6 (old php version)
sudo a2enmod  php7.4 (new php version)
```

Now try it again.

Comment: Hi mon, thanks. I get: ERROR: Module php5.6 does not exist! and Module php7.4 already enabled

Comment: type your old version number